# xacro property names not recognised by roslaunch

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

ROS version: Melodic

I've been trying to implement xacro into a very simple robot to help tidy up and future-proof it, however when I use roslaunch to load the file into rviz it gives me the following error:

```
Unable to parse component [${wb_w}] to a double (while parsing a vector value)
```

Ive tried launching the file with the following commands with the same results:

```
roslaunch omni_description display.launch model:='$(find omni_description)/urdf/omni.urdf.xacro'

roslaunch omni_description display.launch model:='$(find omni_description)/urdf/omni.urdf'
```

The code in question is shown below (Only the sections where xacro has been implemented are shown as i have only tried it on one link so far, let me know if you need the rest.)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="omni">
<xacro:property name="wb_w" value="0.18"/>
<xacro:property name="wb_h" value="0.005"/>
<xacro:property name="wb_d" value="0.18"/>
<xacro:property name="wb_m" value="0.23"/>

<xacro:property name="w_r" value="0.18"/>
<xacro:property name="w_l" value="0.18"/>
<xacro:property name="w_m" value="0.60"/>

<xacro:property name="b_r" value="0.024"/>
<xacro:property name="b_m" value="0.60"/>

<xacro:macro name="wb_inertial" params="mass depth width height">
  <inertial>
    <mass value="${mass}"/>
    <inertia 
              ixx="${(1/12)*mass*(width+height)}" 
              ixy="0.0" 
              ixz="0.0" 
              iyy="${(1/12)*mass*(depth+height)}" 
              iyz="0.0" 
              izz="${(1/12)*mass*(width+depth)}" />
  </inertial>
</xacro:macro>

  <link name = "wheel_base">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size = "${wb_w} ${wb_d} ${wb_h}"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size = "${wb_w} ${wb_d} ${wb_h}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:wb_inertial mass="${wb_m}" depth="${wb_d*wb_d}" width="${wb_w*wb_w}" height="${wb_h*wb_h}"/>
  </link>
```

**EDIT 1**:

The typos have been fixed and the same error has presented itself, when running via roslaunch the same error message is returned:

```
Unable to parse component [${wb_w}] to a double (while parsing a vector value)
```

**EDIT 2**

I have included the launch file below:

```
<launch>

  <arg name="gui" default="true" />

  <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find omni_description)/urdf/omni.urdf" />
  <param name="use_gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>

  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find omni_description)/urdf.rviz" required="true" />

</launch>
```

**EDIT 3**

I have checked the file using *check_urdf* and recieved a slightly more detailed error:

```
Error:   Unable to parse component [${wb_w}] to a double (while parsing a vector value)
         at line 157 in /build/urdfdom-ACOcA8/urdfdom-1.0.0/urdf_parser/src/link.cpp
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334665/xacro-property-names-not-recognised-by-roslaunch/) by [GPPWalton](https://answers.ros.org/users/36357/gppwalton/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-10-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-10-07**:
I see a typo in `<xacro:wb_inertial mass="${wb_m}" depth="${wb_d*wb_d}" width="${wb_w*wb*w}" height="${wb_h*wb_h}"/>` in width. Correct that and see if it works, because rest seems fine.

**Comment by [GPPWalton](https://answers.ros.org/users/36357/gppwalton/) on 2019-10-07**:
@Choco93 Im struggling to see the typo in that tag, could you point it out?

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-10-08**:
`width="${wb_w*wb*w}"` should be `width="${wb_w*wb_w}"`

**Comment by [GPPWalton](https://answers.ros.org/users/36357/gppwalton/) on 2019-10-08**:
@Choco93 Thanks, I can't believe I missed that, I'll fix the typo and see what that does.

**Comment by [GPPWalton](https://answers.ros.org/users/36357/gppwalton/) on 2019-10-08**:
@Choco93 I've fixed the typo but it has not solved the error.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-10-08**:
That's indeed stange but that shouldn't prevent your launch file from running without errors (I mean the node not crashing) since when converting from `xacro` to `urdf` the parsing is correctly done (at leat when i tried and I've the same error using `check_urdf`).

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-10-08**:
Can you show your launch file ?

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-10-08**:
I had similar issue, but I was parsing through yaml and it has some restrictions there, but your xacro seems fine to me.

**Comment by [GPPWalton](https://answers.ros.org/users/36357/gppwalton/) on 2019-10-08**:
@Delb Yeah I'll edit the post with the launch file.

**Comment by [GPPWalton](https://answers.ros.org/users/36357/gppwalton/) on 2019-10-08**:
@Delb and @Choco93, I just ran `check_urdf` and `gz sdf` and recieved the same error, with the addition of the position, I've updated the post with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your error is due to how you load the parameter `robot_description`, you don't actually call `xacro` to parse the file when using this :

```
<param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find omni_description)/urdf/omni.urdf" />
```

What it should be is :

```
  <arg name="model" default="$(find omni_description)/urdf/omni.urdf.xacro"/>
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(arg model)" />
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2